# Express Application in AWS Lambda has base64 encoded body every single time

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

I'm making post requests to an AWS Api gateway with a lambda proxy integration pointing to a lambda function. This lambda function is a wrapper for an existing express application. I could decode the body myself and set the body to be appropriately formatted, but I don't have to do this when I run the express server manually. I'm essentially trying to avoid adding middleware that checks if it's a lambda function, then setting the body to be the decoded JSON of the body. I thought this would be an easy fix (and it probably is), but I'm not sure how to do it.

All requests are made from Postman with x-www-form-urlencoded.

I've tried messing around with some of the body parsers, binarymimetypes, doing application/json on postman, using awsserverless event context middleware.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use((request, response, next) => {
    console.log("GOT BODY!");
    console.log(request.body);
    next();
});
```

The above code prints the base64 encoded value if the app is on aws lambda and prints the correct JSON value if running locally.

Comment: Did you solve it? Have the same issue...